# Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments

Tags: windows-installer

How can I enable *logging* in my *MSI project* and set `MsiLogFileLocation`? Now I am running my `setup.msi` with command line arguments:

```
msiexec /i install.msi /l*v InstallLog.log
```

I want to log my work always just running `setup.msi` without any arguments. Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***One Line Logging How-to:*** Install **`Your.msi`** and create a verbose log file. More below.

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

---

> ***From the MSI SDK***: "*You can enable verbose logging on the user's computer by using [Command Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/command-line-options), the [MsiLogging
> property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msilogging), [Logging policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/logging), [MsiEnableLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Msi/nf-msi-msienableloga), and
> [EnableLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/installer-enablelog) method*".
>
> ***Short Answer***: So add the property **[MsiLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msilogging)** property to your MSI's [Property Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-table) and maybe use **`"vp"`** as value (without the quotes).

---

> ***Hot Debugging Tip***: Search for ["**value 3**"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) in the log file to find errors as explained by [**`Rob Mensching`**](https://twitter.com/robmen) (Wix & Orca author). MSI log files can be overwhelming otherwise. See more on log-interpretation below (yellow section).

---

- [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340978/129130)
- [On the MSI logging switches and content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341837/129130)

---

***Burn***: **`WiX Burn Bundles`** (**`setup.exe`** launchers) have their own logging constructs (beyond the MSI-specific logging described above). In other words MSI files have their logging, and **`setup.exe`** burn launchers have theirs.

- [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44347702/129130), and [from Rob Mensching himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18755775/129130) (WiX benevolency).
- ***RECOMMENDED***: **https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407**

***Setup.exe Extraction***: [Burn setup.exe bundles can also be extracted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512) (information on extraction of MSI files and setup.exe in general) - in other words you can uncompress the setup.exe contents to an output folder. Here is an inline example (follow link for more):

```
dark.exe -x outputfolder setup.exe
```

**`dark.exe`** is a WiX binary - [install WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) ([WiX quick start links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)) first in order to extract a WiX setup.exe (as of now - might change?). [More on dark.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546) (section 4).

---

***Express Logging (Verbose)***: Simplest possible, verbose logging from **`cmd.exe`**.

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

***Quick Parameter Explanation***:

```
 /i = run install sequence 
 /L*v C:\Your.log = verbose logging at specified path
```

---

***Debug Logging (Verbose)***: Advanced, slow logging for maximum details captured.

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log
```

***Quick Parameter Explanation***:

```
 /i = run install sequence 
 /L*vx! C:\Your.log = verbose debug logging at specified path

 The x adds extra debugging information, and the ! disables the log buffer.
 This means there is no lost log if there are any crashes.
```

---

### All MSI Packages - Global Logging (policy)

Yes, you **`enable logging globally on the machine`** by setting the appropriate registry key. Each MSI launched will then cause a log file with a temporary name to be created in the **`TEMP`** folder. Sort file list by change date to get the most recent one.

***Registry Key & Value***: The actual registry settings:

```xml
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
"Logging"="voicewarmup"
"Debug"=dword:00000007
```

***How-To***: Please see this FAQ-entry from installsite.org, section "**`Globally for all setups on a machine`**": http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm for the exact procedure.

***Heads-Up*** (technical detail): **`This is a very technical problem that may have a bothersome and highly unexpected pragmatic effect`**. A side-effect of this global logging is that any [Session objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/session-object) you instantiate from a script using the [MSI-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-reference) will also create a log file in the TEMP folder. This can cause hundreds of log files to be created in the TEMP folder if you [iterate all packages and instantiate a session object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48615123/129130). **Also in the Event Log** (a big system administrator no-no!). Very specific problem, but just pointing it out. A cleanup of the temp folder and Event Log "solves" the problem - or better yet - just avoid creation Session objects. Note that your deployment tool could instantiate session objects unexpectedly. Maybe check after enabling logging so you don't get this silly problem network-wide.

---

### Package-Specific Logging

Apart from global settings and policies, you can customize the logging per package via properties or custom actions or just specify options and logging location via the **msiexec.exe command line**.

***Command Line***: In its simplest form: `msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log`. Documentation for the [msiexec.exe command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/command-line-options) (look at section for switch: `/L`)

***Properties***: You can set the [MsiLogging property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msilogging) in each package to customize logging. The MSI property [MsiLogFileLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msilogfilelocation) holds the path to the log file. Use this if you want to open the log after installation.

***Custom Action***: You could investigate the [**`Installer.EnableLog method`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/installer-enablelog) of the [MSI-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-reference) to customize the logging behavior for a specific MSI from a custom action. More: [Windows Installer Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-logging).

---

### Interpreting MSI Log Files

> On the topic of interpreting log files: [**How to interpret an MSI Log
> File**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367). And [one more answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341837/129130).
>
> ***Direct Link***: [**`Direct PDF Link to Robert Macdonald's log guide`**](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf) (resurrected from Wayback).
>
> ***Find Errors***: And, as stated above: search for ["**value 3**"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) in the log file to find errors as explained by [**`Rob Mensching`**](https://twitter.com/robmen) (Wix & Orca author). MSI log files can be overwhelming otherwise.
>
> ***Advanced Installer***: [**How Do I Read a Windows Installer Verbose Log File?**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html)
>
> ***Logging Tool***: Some information on the MSI SDK logging tool [WiLogUtl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64341837/129130) and how to enable debugging logging with slow, constant log writes to capture as much debugging information as possible.

---

***Writing to Log***: Writing to the MSI log file from your own **custom actions** is not that hard. Here is a primer on the subject from **Robert Dickau**: [MSI Tip: Writing to the Log File from a Custom Action](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf).

- [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362793/129130)
- [C# / Managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573250/129130)

---

***Some Links***:

- [**Windows Installer Logging**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-logging) (lots of core information, do read)
- [**Windows Installer Best Practice**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-best-practices#enable-verbose-logging-on-users-computer-when-troubleshooting-deployment) (verbose logging for troubleshooting)
- [MSI installation log says: Note: 1: 2205 2: 3: Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417893/msi-installation-log-says-note-1-2205-2-3-error/25435817#25435817)
- [In-use files not updated by MSI-installer (Visual Studio Installer project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385973/in-use-files-not-updated-by-msi-installer-visual-studio-installer-project/51387298#51387298)
- [How Do I Read a Windows Installer Verbose Log File?](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html)
- [How to Reproduce MSI Install Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137866/how-to-reproduce-msi-install-error/48138503#48138503)
- [How To Read A Windows Installer Verbose Log](http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/02/05/how-to-read-a-windows-installer-verbose-log.aspx)
- [Difference between msiexec log /lv VS /l*v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341212/difference-between-msiexec-log-lv-vs-lv/64341837#64341837)

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answer. Is it possible through custom actions?
Suppose we can add that registry key during installation and remove it after completing installation.

Comment: You can [write to the log file](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf) relatively easily, and you should be able to log to the Event Viewer as well - if you code it yourself. It depends on your actual scenario and what you need to achieve? With some coding you might be able to kick off the log file from the setup finish dialog? Do not meddle with that key during installation.

Comment: Please see updated answer and the `Installer.EnableLog method` of the `MSI API`. I have never used it, since I don't want to mess with the global logging configuration.

Comment: I would add the "x" (extra debug) option to the logging parameter "/L", e. g. "/L*vx". This proved actually useful for my recent problem analysis. For one, it adds the "client state" information to the feature/component state logging. Also I believe it shows information about MSI handle leaks and propably other useful stuff. I wouldn't enable it for regular logging as part of a normal setup though, as it could slow down the setup.

Comment: Great idea. I will add that, and also the **flush to log** option **`!`** - which enables continuous writing of the log file without a buffer - so that you get all the log if there is a crash in custom actions for example (no lost buffer). This flush to log option may drastically slow down installation.

Comment: Updated the answer, might be a bit too much information - or too messy as presented. Will wait a while and look at it again with fresh eyes. Thanks for the hint - that **`x option`** is easy to forget.

Answer (score 1):

To enable auto logging for `MSI` installer it needs to be edit with `Orca` to set an appropriate value for `MsiLogging` property. `MSI` is editable with [`Orca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/orca-exe), the official MS tool for editing `MSI` packages.
`MSI` packages are not executable binaries but rather a Database with data defining the installation process. We can add the [`MsiLogging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/msilogging) property with value [`v`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging).

[image: This image shows Orca UI to edit MSI to enable logging.]

([ref](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/alc25y/msi_installer_log_generation/effgcrg))