# MSIEXEC: "Executing op: ShortcutRemove" step is very slow

Tags: windows-installer

We have ".msi" installation package.
I try to uninstall it with appropriate commnd:

```
MsiExec.exe /x{5D719E68-C010-4DD9-A1C3-7BC1581781F0} /lv log.txt
```

In the log I see follow records:

```
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:41:595]: Executing op: ShortcutRemove(Name=n80p5njq|Sample Playlist Transcoding)
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:41:601]: Verifying accessibility of file: Sample Playlist Transcoding.lnk
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:41:602]: Using source file security for destination.
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:41:602]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Config.Msi\b5120.rbf 
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:46:847]: Executing op: ShortcutRemove(Name=8vdz7yeg|Sample Writer)
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:46:853]: Verifying accessibility of file: Sample Writer.lnk
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:46:855]: Using source file security for destination.
MSI (s) (D4:14) [17:38:46:856]: Note: 1: 2318 2: C:\Config.Msi\b5121.rbf
```

All steps are taken acceptable interval except "ShortcutRemove".
What can I do, for increase the speed of uninstall process?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Was it a networking issue?

Comment: Actually no... I was glad to have your answer, and marked it as right, but I think it will take much time to understand, what the problem. Enyway... all shortcut nodes of msi didn't point to network. It seems some mutual lock of files in the msi framework.

Comment: OK, then you might need more information. Let me extend the answer with some information on debugging logging and maybe some other links. Is this MSI compiled from a WiX source? Is it on [github.com](https://www.github.com)? A quick look at the source is usually revealing.

Comment: I see you work with embedded stuff? Where does that shortcut actually point? What is it pointing to? Is the binary on some embedded device? Is that a URL? Is it a mapped drive? Or some other reference? Just trying to find the overall setup logic.

Comment: Added some stuff in my answer below.

Comment: 1. I tried to search you over the net, but it seems that you are very hide your identity ) 2. Yes, it actually from WiX. 3. It pointing to binary which is installed in same foled, no network device. Some time before it was working nice, I thing it related to MSI update, not to our code. 4. All my collegues who deals with it leaved for a business trip... So I can not get this issue into the deep... They will come in a week ) My telegramm @theservercat )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***: A few questions:

- If you remove the shortcuts in a test version, is the uninstall quick?
- Is the binary on some embedded device?
- Does the shortcut point to a URL, a local path, a network path or some other resource - like a mapped drive letter?
- If you do a major upgrade, is that equally slow to uninstall?
- Is the behavior different if the embedded device (if any) is connected and not in sleep or hibernation mode while you uninstall?

---

***Need For Speed***: I have some general **`"MSI speed improvement suggestions"`** here in this old answer from [serverfault.com](https://www.serverfault.com): [**How can I speed up MSI package install and uninstall?**](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall)

I would try the [**`MSIFASTINSTALL`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property and set it to either **`3`** or **`7`**.

---

***Debug Logging (Verbose)***: You can sometimes get better information by using a **`debugging logging option`**. Here is a command line to use advanced, slow logging for maximum details captured:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Path\Your.log
```

***Logging Links***: Here is more information and links on MSI logging: [Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) - this also contains a parameter explanation section for the command line used above. Please check it out. Also check the section "*Interpreting MSI Log Files*".

---

***Links***:

- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933) (various ways to uninstall)