# Microsoft Service Managment Automation

Tags: installation

I have a problem with installing the SMA (Microsoft Service Managment Automation) web service.
The installation fails every time. Can somebody help me with it.

Comment: Off topic here, but here are some tips: always check all **event logs**, **application logs** and **MSI logs** - if available. Just to mention it. And use any debugging tool available and google the exact error message before doing anything else. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) - down the page.

Comment: Try installing on another system first of all, maybe a virtual. Also try installing using a different admin-privilege user account (sorts some weird issues).

Comment: I have tried it with another user is not working.
Of course I have the problem in gegoogle searched but there is no solution

Comment: [On logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130), please create a proper log and use those hints to debug. Search for 'value 3' first.

Comment: Suggest you talk to your system administrator and send him [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/deploy?view=sc-sma-2019) or a better one. Database connection involved and IIS - lots of stuff that can fall over. They might even have a UAT environment, who knows. Also check serverfault.com maybe or a dedicated forum for this software.