# How to log custom messages in Wix Installer code?

Tags: c#, installation, wix, wix3, wix3.7

Here is my Wix code in `.wxs` file

```
      <Component Id="MyRootCA.cer" Guid="*" Permanent="yes">
      <File Id="MyRootCAFile.cer" Name="MyRootCA.cer" Source="Assets\Certificates\MyRootCA.cer" />
      <iis:Certificate Id="Certificate.MyRootCA"
                       Name="MyRootCA.cer"
                       Request="no"
                       StoreLocation="localMachine"
                       StoreName="root"
                       Overwrite="no"
                       BinaryKey="MyRootCABinary"/>
     </Component>
```

The certificate is successfully installed on the machine after installation. Now, how do I log the message about this operation?

I am executing below command, and it generates log file

```
  msiexec /i installer.msi /L*vx c:\work\Test2.log /q
```

How do I add, custom messages to this log file? I would like to add a success message for adding a certificate to the system

I am trying to add `custom action`

```
  <CustomAction Id="CA.LogCertificateInstallation"
                BinaryKey="BI.CA"
                DllEntry="LogCertificateInstallation"
                Execute="deferred"
                Return="check"
                Impersonate="no"/>
```

How do I link this custom action to above `Component`?

Comment: [A quick link for now](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf). I have answer on this before, you could try searching for it (heading out right now).

Comment: Is this link valid for c#/Visual studio?

Comment: Those samples are valid for any tool that can create MSI custom actions. I don't have any sample code for C#, but the WiX custom action templates do. In Visual Studio, go to *"Add new project..."* and select *"C# Custom Action Project for WiX v3"*. The code is something like: `session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");`

Comment: How do I link this custom action to above Component?

Comment: Did you see my suggestion below to use the "Vital" flag? That would probably be enough, hence eliminating unwanted complexity.

Comment: yes, works great!

Comment: Cool, I didn't remember that setting at first. Just wanted to make sure you got the message. So much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Vital***: You can make a setup fail if a vital file is not correctly installed by setting the **`Vital attribute`** to yes in WiX
>   in this fashion:
>
> ```
> <File Source="MyFile.exe" Vital="yes" />
> ```
>
> *"If the installation of a file with the **`msidbFileAttributesVital`** attribute fails, the installation stops and is rolled back"*. [FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-table) - see *`"Attributes"`* section.

---

***Default Logging***: I don't use the **`IIS / Certificate element`** regularly, but I would be very surprised if it didn't do any logging. I would try to read the log again. That log command should do, please check [more on logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) (section: ***`"Interpreting MSI Log Files"`***).

***Custom Logging***: [This document from Robert Dickau](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf) shows valid custom action code for any tool that can create MSI custom actions. He shows **`VBScript`**, **`C++`** and **`Installscript`** custom actions. I don't have any sample code for **`C#`**, but the WiX custom action templates do.

***WiX CA Project***: [WiX Quick Start Links (including downloads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). In Visual Studio, go to *"Add new project..."* and select *"C# Custom Action Project for WiX v3"*. The entry looks something like this:

[image: C# custom action]

Once you have the Custom Action project, the logging code is something like this:

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin CustomAction1");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if Component Id="MyRootCA.cer" fails? I am not able to connect the information.

Comment: Did you try to set the file vital? `<File Source="MyFile.exe" Vital="yes" />`. *"If the installation of a file with the `msidbFileAttributesVital` attribute fails, the installation stops and is rolled back"*. [FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-table) - see "Attributes" section.