# Google Video Support Pluggin Installer tasks consuming CPU

Tags: windows, google-chrome, plugins, windows-installer, taskmanager

Hi it's been few days having different Google Video Support Pluggin Installer tasks running

It happens the same this folk described [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/19033550?hl=en): 
v78 of Chrome, Win 10, Every few hours a new instance of the video plugin installer exe kicks off and runs in parallel with the other(s) in place. Each instance takes ~ half a core and there is also always one MsiExec that terminates (similar usage) when the process is manually killed in task manager. The processes originate from \users\\appdata\local\google\update\install{GUID} - deleting the directories / files does no good, the updater downloads it after a few hours and tries again.

Video plugin installer is v 19.9.2600.0, 10,692,592 bytes

I'd like a way to stop this automated install or have it succeed. It seems I can do neither right now.

Any solutions to this in place?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That installer MSI, is it somewhere to download? Would like to find some details such as product code to check my own system.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Quick Questions***: **`1)`** Are you behind an internet *`proxy server`*? **`2)`** What is your *`security tool`* / malware suite / anti-virus? Can you
>   temporarily disable it whilst the installation finishes? **`3)`** [Have a look
>   in the *`"Deployment Mnemonic"`* section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130)? (for various causes of
>   deployment failure). **`4)`** You can try to *`log in as another user`* and install fresh - see if that works. If it does, then you need a Chrome profile cleanup? **`5)`** There is always *`the reboot`*. Always try that first to get it out of the way as the *`"one-size-doesn't-fit-anyone-at-all-really fix"`*.

---

***Technical***: If I were to guess the problem is a custom action in the MSI that gets stuck "somehow". How many ***`msiexec.exe`*** entries are in the tast list and what context are they in? (`user`, `system`). [There can be many msiexec.exe processes](https://serverfault.com/a/67161/20599). Below is information on how to debug custom action failures (and other failures) by log analysis.

---

***Logging***: If this really is an MSI installer (Windows Installer), then you can try to enable MSI logging policy to create a log file for all MSI installations that run by following the instructions in the section [***`"Globally for all setups on a machine"`*** here](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm). You will then find a log file in the TEMP folder after the installer has run (whenever that might be). Look for **`*.log`** files with a random name. Just sort the folder by change date to see the most recent files.

***`Open Temp folder`***:  <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> > Tap <kbd>R</kbd> > Type: **`%TEMP%`** > Press: <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***Debugging***: You can search the log for ["value 3"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) first to find errors (see Rob Mensching's explanation in that link). You can find more information on interpreting MSI log files in the section ***`"Interpreting MSI Log Files"`*** here: [Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)