# Wix Installer - Re-installation fails - Azure Machine

Tags: azure, wix

Application(`Wix` installer) not getting install when trying for re-installation in Azure machine.

followed steps:

1. Application installed properly in Virtual Machines and Physical
   machines.
2. Application installed properly in the Azure machine for the first time.
3. Application throwing error while installing a second time in Azure machines.

**Event Viewer log:**

```
Product: TableView 16.1 -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: runAdminAppConfigManager, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Scientific Games\TableView\Admin Application\Configuration Manager\, command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Scientific Games\TableView\Admin Application\Configuration Manager\Bally.TableView.ConfigurationManager.exe "false" "false" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Scientific Games\TableView\Configuration.xml"
```

**Product.wxs** file:

```
<CustomAction  Id="runAdminAppConfigManager"  Directory="ADMINAPPCONFIGURATIONMANAGERFOLDER"  ExeCommand='[ADMINAPPCONFIGURATIONMANAGERFOLDER]Bally.TableView.ConfigurationManager.exe "false" "false" "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]Configuration.xml"'  Execute="deferred"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="runAdminAppConfigManager" After="SchedXmlFile" >
        NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH AND  <![CDATA[ADDLOCAL >< "AdminAppFeature"]]>
      </Custom>
```

Installer UI Exception:

[UI Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrhoR.png)

Comment: Typical error from a failing custom action. What does the log file say? [How to create a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). And what is this EXE file that you run via the custom action? What does it do?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, the EXE is the configuration manager which get input from user through simple UI and write it in web.config file.i have created Verbose and process monitor logs which says the same event viewer logs. i could not able to attach it.

Comment: yeah it could be typical error, still why the problem exist only in Azure machines.

Comment: It might be a different custom action causing the problem and you should create a log to verify. Search for ***"value 3"*** to find most likely culprit in the log. If I were to guess it might be a missing runtime (`.NET`, `VCRedist`, `etc...`), a blocking mechanism such as anti virus or any number of other things. [Here is a list of suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) (search for "generic tricks").