# MSI Installer throws exit code 3010 and couldn't fix it. Help needed

Tags: cmd, wix, installshield, windows-installer

Uninstalling existing msi - Success
Installing msi - exit with error code 3010

```
mySoftware.exe /s /v" /quiet /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress ADDLOCAL="mySoftwareConfig" /L*v "%mySoftwareLogFile%" /clone_wait
```

How do i prevent my msi throwing error code 3010 which is causing my successor code pause and exit.

Attached the MSI Log extract

```
MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:676]: Product: mySoftwareTest -- Configuration completed successfully.

MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:677]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: mySoftwareTest. Product Version: 4.5 Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: mySoftwareCompany. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:677]: Value of RebootAction property is 
MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:677]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: mySoftwareTest. Product Version: 4.5. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: mySoftwareCompany. Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 1.

MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:677]: Product: mySoftwareTest. Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect.  The restart was deferred to a later time.

MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:744]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (78:A4) [16:42:14:744]: MainEngineThread is returning 3010
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:801]: RESTART MANAGER: Previously shut down applications have been restarted.
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:802]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:802]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 4/1/2020  16:42:14 ===
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:814]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:814]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:814]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:814]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:819]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:819]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:822]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (78:E8) [16:42:14:824]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (78:DC) [16:42:14:824]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (54:CC) [16:42:14:825]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (54:CC) [16:42:14:826]: MainEngineThread is returning 3010
MSI (c) (54:48) [16:42:14:832]: RESTART MANAGER: Previously shut down applications have been restarted.
MSI (c) (54:48) [16:42:14:833]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
=== Verbose logging stopped: 4/1/2020  16:42:14 ===
```

Comment: [Error code 3010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes) (look towards bottom) - that should generally mean that a reboot is required. To figure out why, [try to make a proper MSI log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) or check the event logs on the system as a first step. Most likely you have a service that isn't stopped properly and there are pending file rename operations scheduled. Test your service for stop and start scenarios to see if that works OK.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul  I have updated the MSI log in my question .Kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

Need to reply as an answer - will evolve it if need be.

First please check and report what is under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback`

Are you testing on a virtual? Did you do a reboot and try again?

It says the [reboot reason](https://github.com/jmalak/open-watcom-v2-test/blob/e988af73f19649514b37b6ecfcb2c83ffd32cf3e/bld/w32api/include/msidefs.mh#L521) is for `"replacing in use files"` and the [reboot type](https://github.com/jmalak/open-watcom-v2-test/blob/e988af73f19649514b37b6ecfcb2c83ffd32cf3e/bld/w32api/include/msidefs.mh#L516) is `"deferred"`.

The exact files involved should be logged in that log file. First I would check if they involve Windows Services and core runtimes.