# Inconsistent MSI behavior

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installaware

We use InstallAware 18.   I've noticed some inconsistent behavior.

**Installation Context changes without my knowing.**
If I double click on the MSI I've built I usually can expect a per-User Installation.  That's fine for us.
*HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp.msi*

However, after a few hours of testing the msi in a Powershell script, the MSI ends up doing a per-machine installation
*HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp.msi*

NOTE:
Even if I use msiexec.exe, I run into this issue.  I'm not using the **ALLUSERS** property from the command line, nor do I have the value set in the MSI.

Comment: What do the logs say? [On MSI logging and interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). And obviously check the property table to verify that ALLUSERS isn't set there anyway. Maybe the tool suddenly added it?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul  I'll revisit the logs.  I'm still relatively new to this, and that log file is a little confusing to me.

Comment: [This annotated MSI log (PDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf) might help. Also see the whole section called ["Interpreting MSI Log Files" here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130) for more tips. In your case I would search for `ALLUSERS`.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul  Again, thank you.  I'm pouring through documentation, and what's becoming very obvious is that I don't know enough to ask the right questions and am therefore going down many rabbit holes.

Answer (score 0):

[Credit to: [Stein Asmul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul).  The Links he posted gave me better questions to ask and got me on the trail to my eventual answer]

If you don't set the **ALLUSERS** property to some value yourself, the system will pick whatever it deems best (e.g. Is the install running as an Admin, or a regular user)

Now, I set ALLUSERS to "TRUE" within my MSI script.  When I double click on the file, I get a Per-machine install.

NOTE: (/q *flag seems to ignore 'ALLUSERS' property*)
msiexec.exe /i myapp.msi -- gets a per-machine install.
msiexec.exe /i myapp.msi /qn -- get a per-user install.

After repeated testing, I can say that /q definitely causes MSIEXEC.exe to ignore ALLUERS=TRUE (or change it to FALSE).  I'm not sure why. Perhaps this is unique to the InstallAware product; I can't be sure; I'm still learning

Comment: Check what default custom actions the product injects into the MSI and check their names. See if any of them ring a bell as to adjusting ALLUSERS.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul  I'll do that.  Thanks