# Difference between msiexec log /lv VS /l*v

Tags: windows-installer

[Microsoft's documentation for msiexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) says this:

> /lv   Turns on logging and **includes verbose** output in the output log file.
>
> /l*   Turns on logging and logs all information, **except verbose** information (/lv) or extra debugging information (/lx).
>
> Examples
>
> To install package C:\example.msi, using a normal installation process with ***all logging information provided, including verbose output***, and storing the output log file at C:\package.log, type:
>
> `msiexec.exe /i "C:\example.msi" /L*V "C:\package.log"`

I think it might help to have an example installer log. **What is 'all logging information' (`/L*V`) vs 'verbose logging' (`/LV`)?** Isn't verbose just that & historically shows all logging info? Guessing this is going to be a unique Microsoft thing

Answer (score 4):

***Debug Logging (Verbose)***: Advanced, slow logging for maximum details captured. This is - as far as I can tell - the most information you can capture in an MSI log:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log
```

---

***Interpreting MSI logs***: MSI log files can be very verbose indeed. Advanced installer and an old blog from the MSI team of many years ago have a few clues to their content:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html
- [How to interpret an MSI Log File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/richard_macdonald/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs) (and the [actual PDF resurrected from WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf))

This old dialog from a log-command generation tool might help. The flush to log means the log is written directly and continuously and not in batches. This continuous writing slows things down a lot, but no log buffer is lost if there is a crash:

[image: Generate MSI command line]

---

[***WiLogUtl.exe***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/wilogutl-exe): The Windows SDK contains this tool to analyze MSI log files. It can be helpful, although it is quite old-fashioned to look at GUI-wise. Search for it under: **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`** - if you have Visual Studio or the Windows SDK installed. Here is a screen shot:

[image: WiLogUtl.exe]

---

Some pre-existing answers on logging:

- [**A comprehensive answer on logging**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)
- Stefan Kruger on logging: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm

Answer (score 2):

The `/l` switch takes a bunch of switches, each of which identifies particular items to log and is independent of the others. Likewise, `v` indicates a particular set of items to be logged; it's not a generic verbose logging level.

`/l*` says include all the switches except for `v` and `x` so it's equivalent to `/loicewarmup`. `/l*vx` includes all the switches and adds `v` and `x` to get everything.

Comment: Do you mean `/voicewarmup` with a V? Can you explain what that is, this appears to be [an article you can link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/enable-windows-installer-logging). Guessing its telling Windows to log ALL .MSI installs vs telling msiexec to log THIS install file?

Comment: No, the logging switch always starts with `/l`. Logging policy applies to all installs; the `/l` switch applies to one install.