# How to view msi status messages above progress bar in PowerShell terminal

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm using a script to install a MSI file in a remote machine. The script runs in VSCODE, writes to PowerShell terminal the exit code.

```
$msiProcess = Start-Process msiexec.exe -Verb "RunAs" -ArgumentList $msiHQArgs -Wait -PassThru
Write-Host $msiProcess.ExitCode
```

How do I display in this terminal the MSI status messages that appeared above the progress bar during installation phase such as "Copying file to...", "Create database...", "Roll back...", "Register..." etc...

Comment: I think your only option is to request that a _log file_ be created - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/45375 - which you can parse in real time to infer progress information - use `!` to disable output buffering.