# wix MSI doesn't launch when I run it from CMD using /quiet parameter

Tags: wix

I created MSI installer using WiX.

when I double clicked it, it works, when I install it through CMD it also works, but when I try to install it from CMD using /quiet parameter it does not launch,

I want to launch my installer from CMD like this : setup.msi /quiet

how to do ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Admin Rights***: Please make sure you launch your MSI installer from an elevated command prompt (**`cmd.exe`**):

- Search for **`cmd.exe`** and right click it and select **`Run as Administrator`**.
- Now run the MSI with the **`/quiet`** parameter.

---

***Debugging & Logging***: It helps to create a log file to determine what is going on. [Please see information on MSI logging here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890). You can enable logging for all MSI operations, or define logging via the command line or via settings inside the MSI. Please visit the link for details.

***Express Logging (Verbose)***: Simplest possible, verbose logging from **`cmd.exe`**:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

Comment: That's great. You can find more WiX tips here: `1)` [very long version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864), `2)` [short version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308043/129130).