# Wix Installer. During rollback how can I get the "original" error?

Tags: installation, wix, rollback

After a failed install I need to output the error code of the Custom Action that caused the rollback in the first place.

Is there any way that I can grab a hold of it via some WiX predefined variables?

Comment: If you can run the installer again you can enable the logging policy. This automatically creates a log file in the TMP folder for every MSI operation. See [this comprehensive answer on logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890). There is also this short version of how to do this. See section *"Globally for all setups on a machine"* here: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.