# Why does my IIS installer suddenly throw and error on installation?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, failed-installation

Hi everyone the last few hours ive been sitting with a weird error from my iis installer, that i cant seem to locate, its a MSI installer. Heres my log, hoping someone can show me the right way. Since the log is gigantic here is a zerobin with it.
https://zerobin.net/?9635829223d1e5f9#PByvuFDpzj0DDQPE5/tzgChTHBVw1IDD29wTfmVLwxI=

Comment: [Just some MSI logging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the log for `value 3`. You'll find this. This is very likely your failure.

```
06/05/2022 03:14:39:163] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: Running process 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe' with parameters ' -norestart -sn "W3SVC/1/Root/NoxInstaller"' silently...
INFO   : [06/05/2022 03:14:39:214] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: Process Call Result Code: '0'        Process Exit Code: '1'.
ERROR  : [06/05/2022 03:14:39:215] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: The error indicates that IIS is in 64 bit mode, while this application is a 32 bit application and thus not compatible.
ERROR  : [06/05/2022 03:14:39:215] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: FAILED:  -2147024895
ERROR  : [06/05/2022 03:14:39:215] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: Custom Action failed with code: '0'
INFO   : [06/05/2022 03:14:39:216] [RegisterAspNet                          ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '1'
CustomAction WEBCA_RegisterAspNet returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 03.14.39: InstallExecute. Return value 3.
```