# Microsoft Intune MSI Deployment

Tags: azure, windows-installer, intune

Deployment of msi application via endpoint management using command line option not working

/qn /L*v "%TEMP%\appintall.log"

whats wrong ?

Comment: What does the log say? [MSI logging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130).

Comment: You can not use an environment variable in the install command. You should use a cmd or powershell script if you need to use such a variable